# Protractor stuck at "Using the selenium server at http://..."

Tags: selenium, angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor

**Background:**

I start `protractor` with:

```
$ protractor protractor.eb.conf.js
```

This specifies a remote selenium server.

Sometimes my `protractor` tests just stall at this point:

```
[17:56:33] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:56:33] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://selenium-server.example.com:4444/wd/hub
```

**Questions**:

1. What other information is needed?

   - Capabilities? Only using chrome.
   - Protractor version 5.1.1
2. What is this point in the process?

   - Launcher? Hosted?
   - Waiting for a node to become available?
3. What should I do to troubleshoot?

---

Edit:

- Using remote selenium server.

Answer (score 0):

```
directConnect:true,
```

You can add this in your conf.js file. This will not wait for the selenium server to start.
Coming to your other questions - 
You also need to mention the framework you are using (for instance I use jasmine framework so I mention it like this) -

```
framework: 'jasmine',
```

Comment: I'm using a remote selenium server, so I cannot use direct connect.